# Filtering objects matching a given logical formula

Tags: python, parsing, filter

I have an array of Python objects, and I would like to get all objects that evaluate to true for a given logical formula.

Let's say the objects are tasks in a task tracking system. Each task has a status, an assignee and a due date. Now I'd like to get all objects that evaluate to true for this formula:

```
(assignee=cdecker OR due=tomorrow) AND status=open
```

For things like the object fields (`assignee` and `status`) it would be a simple matter of checking equality, whereas `due=tomorrow` would be a function to be called on the object.

Is there a simple parser that I could use to parse the expression and then evaluate it for all the objects in my starting set (basically wire all literals to function calls)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/). Here's a parser for a grammar that supports equality, boolean ops and nested brackets:

```
from pyparsing import *

expr   = Forward()
factor = Forward()
term   = Forward()

iand   = Literal("AND").suppress()
ior    = Literal("OR").suppress()
ieq    = Literal("=").suppress()
lpar   = Literal("(").suppress()
rpar   = Literal(")").suppress()
ident  = Word(alphas)
atom   = ident | lpar + expr + rpar

factor << Group(atom + ZeroOrMore(ieq + atom))("equal")
term   << Group(factor + ZeroOrMore(iand + term))("and")
expr   << Group(term  + ZeroOrMore(ior + expr))("or")
```

You can apply this to your formulas to obtain tree-alike structures, which you can evaluate at some point later, for example:

```
formula = "(assignee=cdecker OR due=tomorrow) AND status=open"
tree = expr.parseString(formula, parseAll=True)
print tree.asXML()
```

Comment: I have looked into pyparsing before, but the tree is new to me. Walking through the tree from the root and evaluating the equalities I should end up with either true or false for the whole expression right? Any idea on how to do that efficiently?

Comment: Is there any way I can add callbacks for literals to pyparsing?

Comment: @cdecker: yes, look up `setParseAction`.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function that does your tests, then:

```
[obj for obj in list_of_obj if func(obj)]
```

Comment: Uh right,I should have mentioned: the function is user provided and is not known during the development. That's why I asked for a parser.

Comment: What kind of expressions? Could you reduce them to strings and use `getattr(obj,'string')` or are they logic type with comparisons and math?

Comment: They can be simple, but mostly they involve special treatment, so having the parser call functions on the objects while evaluating would give me the freedom to add more filters later.